Why would my rpm stop?
When I leave my car idling and step on the gas my rpm goes up like normal then when it gets almost to the 3 it would stop for a bit or even drop a little then continue on. I know this is not normal so what can be the cause?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/mileage of the car in question?

Are you the same person who asked What controls the engine RPM?

What did your own senses tell you about the engine speed? Did it continue to rise but the tacho stayed still/dropped? Or did you hear/fell the engine sticking at some revs despite increasing the gas/derv? IOW is it a fault with the tacho/sensor/wiring, or with the engine management system, or with the accelerator pedal control itself?
